# https request failing with .Net Framework 2.0 but works with .Net 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, proxy, .net-2.0, httprequest

My asp.net 2.0 application does an internal https request to another URL to get a valid cookie in the response.

When I test this in the .Net 2.0 framework no cookie is returned however with .Net 4 it does work. There is no exception in the response but my gut feeling is it is related to the company proxy and being https. Are there any suggestions besides upgrading to .Net 4.0 (huge task)?

```
        string ticketissuerURL = "https://Securesite";            
        ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ticketissuerURL);

        // Set some reasonable limits on resources used by this request
        request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 4;
        request.MaximumResponseHeadersLength = 4;
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;

        // Pass in current credentials
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows)";

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Is the response (besides the cookies) valid?

Comment: When you change frameworks are you simply changing the target framework of the app pool or are you doing something to the solution itself? Also, would you mind telling us which server you are using?

Comment: To replicate the issue I can simply change the project framework target version and run in debug. I am using a Windows 2008 server.

Comment: I think there must be something different in the request between the two frameworks  but since it is ssl I am having trouble using Fiddler in the environment to confirm.

Comment: To debug ssl In fiddler open tools from menu and click fiddler options, open https tab and enable decrypt https traffic. Don't forget to add this line at beginning of your code WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("localhost:8888"); If it's still not working maybe you downloaded wrong version of fiddler So try install other version.

Comment: You really need to run fiddler to figure this out. You can use the HTTPS interception built into fiddler for this (it basically does a man-in-the-middle 'attack'). I've used it and it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: can you show the difference between the received HTTP RESPONSE between frameworks?

Answer (score 1):

I've checked your code for this [site](https://m.mbank.pl) as cookie source. Cookies were set appropriate for both frameworks in property response.Headers. You can create cookie container to make them visable in response.Cookies propety.

```
request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
```

So looks like the problem is somthing else, maybe proxy or the implementation have changed in .net 4.0 ( and it adds additonal headers which make it work on .net 4.0 for your service). I think it's good idea to inspect real requests. I suggest you to download [fiddler tool](http://fiddler2.com/) and enable https decryption and next compare requests from both frameworks.

Remember to add this line at beginning of your code

```
WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy("localhost:8888");
```

to let fiddler inspect your requests.

Comment: Using fiddler to a localhost is fairly tricky. Localhost generally won't be intercepted even if you explicitly redirect. The foolproof solution is to use you external facing IP address (on your lan) instead of locahost or 127.0.0.1. That forces the traffic to not use the local loop network interface.